# Slugify string in Django

Tags: python, django, string, unique-constraint

I have developed a form, where the user adds his/her `first name` and `last name`.

For the `username` (a `unique` property), I've devised the following method:

`FirstName`: harrY `LastName`: PottEr --> `username`: Harry-Potter

`FirstName`: HARRY `LastName`: POTTER --> `username`: Harry-Potter-1

`FirstName`: harrY `LastName`: PottEr --> `username`: Harry-Potter-2

And so on..

Here's my function definition:

```
def return_slug(firstname, lastname):
    u_username = firstname.title()+'-'+lastname.title()         //Step 1
    u_username = '-'.join(u_username.split())                     //Step 2
    count = User.objects.filter(username=u_username).count()    //Step 3
    if count==0:
        return (u_username)
    else:
        return (u_username+'-%s' % count)
```

I can't figure out what to do before `Step 3` for the implementation. Where should I put `[:len(u_username)]` to compare the strings?

**EDIT:**

This method is applied if there are multiple instances of `Harry-Potter`, by resolving the issue of adding an integer in the end. My question is: How will I check that how what was the last integer appended to `Harry-Potter`.

Comment: you want to create a slug out of the first name and last name ? What do you need to count ?

Comment: @PepperoniPizza: I want to count how many `Harry-Potter-X`, {where `X` is an integer} are present in the database. For example, if `Harry-Potter-56` is there, then the next one should be given the `username` as `Harry-Potter-57`

Comment: Ok i get it, can you post your model, in order to think of a query ?

Comment: @PepperoniPizza: It's the default `User` Django  builtin model. It has `id`, `email`, `username` ,etc. But, why do you need models for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

def return_slug(firstname, lastname):

    # get a slug of the firstname and last name.
    # it will normalize the string and add dashes for spaces
    # i.e. 'HaRrY POTTer' -> 'harry-potter'
    u_username = slugify(unicode('%s %s' % (firstname, lastname)))

    # split the username by the dashes, capitalize each part and re-combine
    # 'harry-potter' -> 'Harry-Potter'
    u_username = '-'.join([x.capitalize() for x in u_username.split('-')])

    # count the number of users that start with the username
    count = User.objects.filter(username__startswith=u_username).count()
    if count == 0:
        return u_username
    else:
        return '%s-%d' % (u_username, count)
```

Comment: I don't think it's correct. Where is it checking how many `Harry-Potter-X` {where `X` is an integer} are present in the database?

Comment: How does that look? It's not tested, but it should do the trick!

Comment: Ahh..I missed the `_startwith`. Rest was working fine. On a different note, my implementation will be fast or yours? Any idea? My method didn't use any `slugify`.

Comment: You should use [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify), it removes characters that won't be allowed in usernames and it normalizes the string. I can't imagine speed is a real concern anyway, this kind of thing is a very standard way of doing things.

Comment: This also capitalises the first character of the words like you said it should be in the examples.

Comment: My method also did that via `string.title()`. Anyways, I've adopted `slugify`. Thanks. :)

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, didn't see that ;-) No worries!

Comment: Hi, consider two objects with same firstname, the first with surname "xxx", the second with "xxxabc". `startswith` would count both of them when returning slug for the first and it might be an issue.

Comment: Yes that's very true; this will give you the uniqueness, but it's not totally perfect. The other option would be to use the [`__regex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex) field lookup for better checks. It would be a fair bit slower but it'll do the job.

Comment: In principle you could also have a third field `IntegerField` in the database to store the number and the function would be more straightforward. It depends on the bigger picture, but you got the options :)